# Problem in writing message from one terminal to another terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, write

I have a user of name `x` in tty1 and `y` in tty2. `x` wants to write some message to `y` and vice-versa. When I typed `write y tty2` in the tty1 terminal, it said:

```
write:you have write permission turned off
write:y has messages disabled
```

I then tried to enable messages:

```
$ mesg
is n
$ mesg y
```

Now I can successfully write a message from `x` to `y` or vice-versa, but the first line of error continues to appear. I have tried logging out and back in again, but the symptom doesn't change. I also looked through the file `/etc/default/devpts` and saw that `TTYMODE=620`.

Comment: On a freshly-installed ubuntu 14.04 desktop system, every tty created when I opened a new terminal window or logged in with ssh was mode 620. Maybe defaults are different on other versions of ubuntu or other methods of logging in (I don't have the means to test logging in via serial ports). I noticed that `/etc/login.defs` has a line that says `TTYPERM 0600`. It had no effect on my ttys, but try changing that to 0620.