# User messages can't be switched on Fedora

Tags: fedora, tty, write

A non-root user X cannot message a user Y. This is despite both users having successfully run `mesg y`. I've tried following advice for similar problems on Ubuntu described in this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136243/problem-in-writing-message-from-one-terminal-to-another-terminal). No luck.

A root user can message anybody.

I have a rough feeling that appropriate configuration of `/etc/login.defs` or PAM configuration files would solve the problem, but don't know enough to troubleshoot further. Any suggestions?

I am locally logged in as user picrin on tty1 and as user iva on tty2. User iva is also sshed into the box.

#### **EDIT #1**

For the sake of completeness here's more info. This is returned by `who`:

```
picrin   tty1         2014-10-18 22:10
iva      pts/1        2014-10-19 10:09 (hostXXX-XXX-XX-X.rangeXXX-XXX.btcentralplus.com)
iva      tty2         2014-10-19 10:13
```

This is returned when user `picrin` executes `write iva tty2`:

```
write: iva has messages disabled on tty2
```

This is returned when user `picrin` executes `write iva pts/1`:

```
write: iva has messages disabled on pts/1
```

This is returned when user `iva` runs `mesg`:

```
is y
```

I'm running Fedora 20.

Comment: When asking for help, please provide the command you are running, and any output generated by the command.

Comment: I have updated my question accordingly @Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is in adding both user `iva` and user `picrin` to the group `tty` and modifying the `/etc/login.defs` to include a line `TTYPERM 0620`. This solves the problem.

Comment: Just an FYI I do not have such an entry in my `/etc/login.defs` and neither of my users are in such a group, `tty`, and `write` works fine for me.

Comment: @slm Interesting. That might be a difference between fedora 19 and fedora 20.

Comment: I have that distro as well and it works the same on both. It works on all the versions of Fedora that I have which varies b/w F3 up to F20. There's something configured strangely on your system, would be my guess.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this on my Fedora 19 system and was able to write messages from user X to user Y as follows.

*user X (samtest)*

In samtest's terminal I ran the following command:

```
$ write saml
blah
blah
blah
Ctrl+D
```

*user Y (saml)*

In saml's terminal I saw the following message:

```
Message from samtest@greeneggs.mydom.net on tty3 at 21:03 ...
blah
blah
blah
EOF
```